# does gSoapWinhttp plugin with gSoap supports linux

Tags: c++, linux, gsoap

I'm using gSoap proxy services for ews and i need SSL and Auth. support for the endpoint. While my prefer platform is Linux. From gSoap documentation http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html found that it has all SSL and Auth. support in C for linux but i'm using C++.

So when i search on google for SSL and Auth. supports with gSoap in C++, i found https://code.google.com/p/gsoapwinhttp/ link for gsoapwinhttp.

gSoap documentation says that it support most of the platform like windows, linux, macOS etc. and gsoapwinhttp use windows library, so i'm bit of confusing does this gsoapwinhttp plugin with gsoap supports linux platform?

Any help appreciated. thank you.

UPDATE: http://markmail.org/message/sprfixg3gna7t57e#query:+page:1+mid:sprfixg3gna7t57e+state:results this link related to my question, but i don't understand what and how to do, (i'm newbie to C++).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gSoap has builtin support for SSL ([gSoap SSL](http://www.cs.fsu.edu/~engelen/soapdoc2.html#tth_sEc19.21)). Even though you are using C++, you can still use the C code and it will work fine. The services generated by `soapcpp2` are inherited from `struct soap` so using the C functions like `soap_ssl_server_context` will still work.